# Replace email inside varchar tsql

Tags: sql, t-sql, replace

I have an email address inside stringified JSON, in a column.

I need to replace it with a different email address.

I should add that I cannot use CLR for this. That would be too easy.

I'll take other suggestions, but the best I've come up with is to replace everything between the `"`s before and after the `@`.

```
DECLARE @testEmailAddress varchar(255);
SET @testEmailAddress = 'MyReplacementEmail@gmail.com'; 
UPDATE #TestEmails
SET 
    COMM_DATA = 
        STUFF (
            COMM_DATA,      
            PATINDEX(
                '%@%', 
                COMM_DATA
            ) 
            -
            PATINDEX ('%"%',
                REVERSE(
                    SUBSTRING(
                        COMM_DATA, 
                        0, 
                        PATINDEX(
                            '%@%', 
                            COMM_DATA
                        )
                    )
                )
            ) + 1,
            PATINDEX(
                '%@%', 
                COMM_DATA
            ) 
            +
            PATINDEX ('%"%',
                SUBSTRING(
                    COMM_DATA, 
                    PATINDEX(
                        '%@%', 
                        COMM_DATA
                    ),
                    LEN(COMM_DATA)
                )
            ) - 1,
            @testEmailAddress
        )
;
```

Which almost works, except that the replacement email address seems to be overrunning the replacement string by several characters.

For example

`{"CustomerEmail":"original@test.com","property2":"value2","property3":"value3","property4":"value4","property5":"value5","property6":"value6","property7":"value7","property8":"value8"}`

becomes

`{"CutomerEmail":"MyReplacementEmail@gmail.comproperty8":"value8"}`

but I expect it to be

`{"CustomerEmail":"MyReplacementEmail@gmail.com","property2":"value2","property3":"value3","property4":"value4","property5":"value5","property6":"value6","property7":"value7","property8":"value8"}`

Comment: Your `'becomes'` is the wrong result or your desire result?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Wrong result. I will clarify and post what I expect.

Comment: Why you dont find the first occurence of `"` after `"CustomerEmail":` ?

Comment: The JSON isn't consistent across records. I can say with a degree of certainty there will only be one email address (and only one `@`) so I'm using that as the starting point of this search.

Comment: But how many `"CustomerEmail":` are there? This is sql server?

Comment: If you are talking about SQL 2016, you know they just added JSON parsing support making it more like parsing XML.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza it's not always named that

Comment: @djangojazz good callout. It's 2008. I WISH it was SQL 2016...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CROSS APLLY is handy for calculations like this one

```
declare @t table (comm_data varchar(max))
insert @t values
('{"CustomerEmail":"original@test.com","property2":"value2","property3":"value3","property4":"value4","property5":"value5","property6":"value6","property7":"value7","property8":"value8"}');

DECLARE @testEmailAddress varchar(255);
SET @testEmailAddress = 'MyReplacementEmail@gmail.com'; 
select t1.*, t2.*, stuff(comm_data,p1-p2+2,p2+p3-3,@testEmailAddress)
from @t 
cross apply (
     select p1=PATINDEX('%@%',COMM_DATA)
    ) t1
cross apply (
     select p2=PATINDEX('%":"%', reverse(left(COMM_DATA,p1))),
       p3 = PATINDEX('%","%', substring(COMM_DATA, p1, len(COMM_DATA)))
    ) t2
```

You can easily debug proper p1-p2+2,p2+p3-3 `stuff` bounds and convert the code to a long form if needed.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something more like this:  Although I bet in SQL 2016 there is a better way to query and replace data than plain string parsing.

```
DECLARE @replace varchar(255) = '"MyReplacementEmail@gmail.com"'; 

DECLARE @JSON VARCHAR(4000) = '{"CustomerEmail":"original@test.com","property2":"value2","property3":"value3","property4":"value4","property5":"value5","property6":"value6","property7":"value7","property8":"value8"}'

DECLARE @Search VARCHAR(128) = '"CustomerEmail"'

DECLARE
    @SearchStart  INT
,   @SearchEnd    INT
,   @ValStart     INT
,   @ValEnd       INT
;

SELECT 
    @SearchStart = CHARINDEX(@Search, @JSON, 1) 
,   @SearchEnd = CHARINDEX(@Search, @JSON, 1) + LEN(@Search) 
,   @ValStart = CHARINDEX(':', @JSON, CHARINDEX(@Search, @JSON, 1) + LEN(@Search)) + 1 
,   @ValEnd = CHARINDEX('"', @JSON, CHARINDEX(@Search, @JSON, 1) + LEN(@Search) + 2) + 1 

SELECT STUFF(@Json, @ValStart, @ValEnd - @ValStart, @replace)
```

I could essentially make this a scalar function that takes a string(varchar JSON) and returns an altered JSON.  You essentially are just key pair hunting in a string.  That way I could run it against a result set and do it N number of times and just require a parameter of what field I was searching(@JSON), what I was 'Key' I was searching to replace(@CustomerEmail), and what I was replacing it with(@replace).

Answer (score 0):

I was miscalculating the end point. Instead of giving the distance between the start and end points for the `STUFF`, I was giving it the starting and ending positions from the start of the string. Final code looks like:

```
    COMM_DATA = 
        STUFF (
            COMM_DATA,      
            PATINDEX(
                '%@%', 
                COMM_DATA
            ) 
            -
            PATINDEX ('%"%',
                REVERSE(
                    SUBSTRING(
                        COMM_DATA, 
                        0, 
                        PATINDEX(
                            '%@%', 
                            COMM_DATA
                        )
                    )
                )
            )+ 1,
            PATINDEX(
                '%@%', 
                COMM_DATA
            ) 
            +
            PATINDEX ('%"%',
                SUBSTRING(
                    COMM_DATA, 
                    PATINDEX(
                        '%@%', 
                        COMM_DATA
                    ),
                    LEN(COMM_DATA)
                )
            )
            -
            (
                PATINDEX(
                    '%@%', 
                    COMM_DATA
                ) 
                -
                PATINDEX ('%"%',
                    REVERSE(
                        SUBSTRING(
                            COMM_DATA, 
                            0, 
                            PATINDEX(
                                '%@%', 
                                COMM_DATA
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            ) - 2,
            @testEmailAddress
        )
```